# simple extension

Tags: field-theory

I am asked to find the simple extension of $\mathbb{Q}(2^\frac{1}{4},i)$. I believe this is equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}(2^\frac{1}{4}+i)$ but I have no idea how to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(2^\frac{1}{4},i) \subset \mathbb{Q}(2^\frac{1}{4}+i)$.

I know how to prove $\mathbb{Q}(3^\frac{1}{2},2^\frac{1}{2})=\mathbb{Q}(3^\frac{1}{2}+2^\frac{1}{2})$ but the same technique doesn't seem to work as easily for the above.

Thanks!

EDIT: Is there no way of simply showing that $i$ or $2^\frac{1}{4}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}(2^\frac{1}{4}+i)$?

Comment: Check your notes. How is the Primitive Element Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem proved? I know only of one proof and the one I know solves this problem easily.

Comment: I don't think my answer below is that complicated. Is there anything I can make more clear? Drop me a line on the answer's comment box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\mathbb{Q} \preceq \mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of{2}) \preceq \mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2}+ i)$.

Therefore $|\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2}+ i):\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2}+ i):\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2})|\cdot |\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2}):\mathbb{Q}|$.

Can you prove that $|\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2}):\mathbb{Q}|=4$?

Let $\alpha = \root 4\of {2} + i$. We have $\alpha = \root 4\of {2} + i \Longrightarrow \alpha - \root 4\of {2}=i \Longrightarrow \alpha ^2 -2\alpha\root 4\of {2} + \sqrt{2}=-1$.

It follows that $\alpha$ is a root of $p(t):=t^2-(2\root 4\of {2}-\sqrt{2}-1)\in\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2})\textbf{[}t \textbf{]}$. So if $p(t)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2})$, then it will be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2})$. Obviously $\alpha \not \in \mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2})\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, so $p(t)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2})$.

It follows that $|\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2}+ i):\mathbb{Q}|=8$.

Now let's prove that $|\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2}, i):\mathbb{Q}|=8$.

We know that $|\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2}, i):\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2}, i):\mathbb{Q}(\root 4 \of {2})|\cdot |\mathbb{Q}(\root 4 \of {2}):\mathbb{Q}|$.

Since $m(t):=t^2+1\in \mathbb{Q}\textbf{[}t\textbf{]}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\root 4 \of {2})\textbf{[} t\textbf{]}$ clearly is the minimal polynomial of $i$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\root 4 \of {2})$, we get $|\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2}, i):\mathbb{Q}(\root 4 \of {2})|=2$. Therefore $|\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2}+ i):\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2}, i):\mathbb{Q}|=8$

Finally fom $\mathbb{Q}(\root 4 \of {2}+i)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\root 4\of {2},i)$ the equality follows.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably using Galois theory. Notice that $\mathbb Q(2^{1/4},i)$ is Galois extension whose automorphisms map $2^{1/4} \mapsto i^j 2^{1/4}$, $j=0,1,2,3$ and $i \mapsto \pm i$. Then it's not hard to see, by comparing real components for instance that $2^{1/4}+i$ is not fixed by any non-identity automorphism, so it must generate the entire field.

Comment: Surely you mean the non-identity automorphisms...

Comment: Yes, of course. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Put

$$x=\sqrt[4]2+i\Longrightarrow(x-i)^4=2\Longrightarrow x^4-4x^3i-6x^2+4xi+1=2\Longrightarrow$$

$$(x^4-(6x^2+1))^2=\left(4xi(x^2-1)\right)^2\Longrightarrow$$

$$ x^8-12x^6-2x^4+36x^4+12x^2+1=-16x^2(x^4-2x^2+1)\Longrightarrow$$

$$x^8+4x^6+2x^4+28x^2+1=0$$

Thus, $\,x\,$ satisfies the above irreducible monic polynomial of degree $\,8\,$ (**), so

$$\begin{align*}(1)&[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4] 2\,,\,i):\Bbb Q]=[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4] 2\,,\,i):\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2][\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2\,,\,\Bbb Q]=2\cdot 4=8\\{}\\
(2)&[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2+i):\Bbb Q]\stackrel{\text{from}(**)}= 8\end{align*}$$

But clearly $\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2+i)\leq\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2\,,\,i)\,$ , and since these two are rational linear spaces of the same finite dimension then they're equal.

Comment: I didn't get how you conclude that that polynomial is irreducible over the rationals.